# A wine taster claims she can distinguish four vintages of a particular Cabernet. What is prob this can be done by guessing? Feedback

Tags: probability, problem-solving

A wine taster claims she can distinguish four vintages of a particular Cabernet. What is prob this can be done by guessing? She is confronted with four unlabeled glasses.

I have a solution to this question, but I also saw a solution elsewhere and I am confident that my solution is actually the correct one.

**My Solution**

Since there are four unlabeled glasses, the taster can either guess correctly or guess wrong for each glass. As such there are $2^{4}$ possible sets of four guesses. There is also only one way of getting all four glasses correct (call this event $A$). As such the probability will be:

$$P(A) = \frac{1}{2^{4}} = \frac{1}{16}$$.

**Other Solution**

[image]

Now thinking about it while writing this post, I think in my solution I considered the glasses as "ordered" whereas in the other solution they treated them as unordered hence difference in sample space size. Could somebody confirm that is actually the case?

Comment: "[T]he taster can either guess correctly or guess wrong for each glass"
While this statement is true, it doesn't necessarily mean that the probability is $\frac 12$. A dice can show either $6$ or not a $6$ but the probabilities are $\frac 16$ and $\frac 56$ respectively.

Comment: Wow....that is extremely subtle. This could turn into a complex Bayesian question based on what you just mentioned. But I do see your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your approach could work in considering each glass to be the right wine or the wrong wine, the probability for each is not $1/2$. Instead, the probability is $1/4$ for the first glass, $1/3$ for the second glass (as, $1/2$ for the third glass, and $1/1$ for the last glass. The probability for each is chosen by assuming that all previous glasses were correctly assigned.

It is easier to look at the first glass as having $4$ possible states: Wine $A$, $B$, $C$, or $D$. Naively, this would make it seem like there is $4^4 = 256$ possible states, but this reduces to $4! = 24$ possible states (with only one right one), since each glass must map one-to-one to the guess of a wine.